# Как расшифровать этот JSON?

Tags: json

Есть JSON не могу расшифровать. Чем он зашифрован? Вроде base64, но расшифровать не получается. Как расшифровать этот JSON?

```
{"data":"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"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Это AES - простой и мощный метод шифрования и дешифрования.

Есть например на JS [библа для этого](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)

Однако для дешифровки нужен ключ, коего тут не предоставлено.

Что представлено как раз в той же библиотеке:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ключ для 
                                                                 шифрования и расшифровки 
                                                                 в последствии
​

encrypted.key
> "74eb593087a982e2a6f5dded54ecd96d1fd0f3d44a58728cdcd40c55227522223 ";
​
encrypted.iv
> "7781157e2629b094f0e3dd48c4d786115";
​
encrypted.salt
> "7a25f9132ec6a8b34";
​
encrypted.ciphertext
> "73e54154a15d1beeb509d9e12f1e462a0";
​
encrypted
> "U2FsdGVkX1+iX5Ey7GqLND5UFUoV0b7rUJ2eEvHkYqA=";
   ^^^^^^^^^^--- указание на этот метод шифрования
```

Comment: Спасибо, вероятно ключ в этом JS, но он огромный, а как его искать? pml.good-game-network.com/pm-leaderboard/main.9efd3daeb095b3380871.js

Comment: Как хотите, так ищите))

Comment: Вначале js beautify, потом поиск по "encrypt" потом дальнейший reverse engineering